# Date format issue for some languages

Tags: android

I have this code:

```
android.text.format.DateFormat.format(format, date).toString();
```

where format is:

```
public static final String RECORDING_NAME_FORMAT = "MM-dd-yyyy hh-mm AA";
```

The output for english (and the ONLY desired output) is:
"10-27-2014 11-12 PM" but the output for catalan is: "10-27-2014 11-12 p.m."

I do not want `"p.m."` I must avoid dots in this situation. Is there any elegant solution besides manually replacing chars?

Comment: I gather then you changed the locale and expected the result to be the same between English locale and Catalan. Well, you can't - since locale formattting, including dates, is uniques per locale - otherwise, we'll be formatting "dd-MM-yyyy" for German locale instead of the correct format "dd.MM.yyyy".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is, I suggest you use `SimpleDateFormat` as it supports using a locale. The code would look something like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy hh-mm AA", Locale.ENGLISH);
sdf.format(date); //Returns string
```

Also, if you want to use the default locale you could use `Locale.getDefault()`